# How was the size of the ring determined in this answer?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just wanted to know how in [his answer for the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185393/318695), user Georges Elencwajg calculated the size for the ring. I was unable to comment there as I just made my account on stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Then if we quotient by the ideal $(x^2)$, we are essentially saying that for any $n\geq 0$, $x^{n+2} \equiv 0 \text{ mod } (x^2)$. This means that the image of any polynomial under the canonical projection $\pi: \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ is of the form $ax+b$. Now simply regard this ring as a vector space, with basis $e_1 = 1$ and $e_2 = x$, then it's clear that it is two dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Unfortunately can not give you an upvote but you have my sincere thanks.

Comment: @acevans Note that although you cannot upvote, you should still be able to 'accept' an answer.

Comment: @johnnycrab ahh I see the link now. Thank you